# UIViewController appearance

Tags: ios, swift, uiappearance

Is it possible to set an appearance for a `UIViewController` subclass?

I would like to have variables like this one

```
dynamic open var doneButtonColor: UIColor?
```

within the `UIViewController` subclass, and style it like this:

```
UIViewControllerSubclass.appearance().doneButtonColor = UIColor.green
```

Comment: have tried with singleton pattern ?

Comment: @NikunjDamani I want to implement `UIAppearance`

Comment: Have you checked out the Wenderlich tutorial on this https://www.raywenderlich.com/108766/uiappearance-tutorial ?

The alternative would be to simply subclass the UIViewController do add whatever controls or settings you know you will always want, and then base everything else on UIMyCustomViewController

Comment: @Russell My problem is that `UIViewController` does not have an `appearnace()`

Comment: This may be a poor comment on my part, but how does a UIViewController *appear*? I noticed that `UIView.appearance()` exists.

Comment: I think it is appearance as in how something looks, not how something becomes visible (appearance has more than 1 meaning in english)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm wondering about the same thing.

Comment: To be honest, I don’t remember, it was 2 years ago